# UserControl Drawing Silverlight 4

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I have created a usercontrol just to contain an Image, because I haveto use Measureoverride and arrangeoverride methods and I can't create a subclass (Image is seled)... anyway, the thing is that when i call this.Image.Measure(SizeIwantto giveto the image) the desiredSize field of the image is not set... anybody know why? 
I have been managing the Layouting methods before and It worked...
Here is the code (I have already checked all the other sizes and none of them is 0 or NaN)

```
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {


        //the size that the element wants to have
        Size imageDesiredSize = new Size();

        imageDesiredSize = availableSize;
        //if the current element's size is a pertentage
        if ((futureHeight != 0))
        {
            imageDesiredSize.Height = availableSize.Height * futureHeight / 100;
        }
        if ((futureWidth != 0))
        {
            imageDesiredSize.Width = availableSize.Width * futureWidth / 100;
        }

        if (widthWrap)
        {
            imageDesiredSize.Width = ((BitmapImage)this.Source).PixelWidth;
        }
        if (heightWrap)
        {
            imageDesiredSize.Height = ((BitmapImage)this.Source).PixelHeight;
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("imagedesired" + imageDesiredSize);
        this.image.Measure(imageDesiredSize);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("desiredsize" + this.image.DesiredSize);

        return imageDesiredSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end It was a really simple solution... In the constructor of the UserControl I added this line:      this.Content = image;
And now the content of the Usercontrol is drawn in the screen :-)